# How to dynamically configure external login providers with ASP.NET Core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I have a multitenant application. The requirement is to provide external login features such as Azure AD, Google, and others. I cannot add the following in the startup.cs because the configuration such as secret and clientId will have to come from the database at runtime for each tenant:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
        {
            options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
        })
         .AddMicrosoftAccount(microsoftOptions =>
         {
             microsoftOptions.ClientId = "clientId from db";
             microsoftOptions.ClientSecret = "secret from db";
         })
```

I have the following two methods in the controller, where on button click POST request is made and I want configure the external login provider at this point:

```
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public IActionResult Login()
    {
        var schemeName = "Microsoft";
        var schemeOptions = new MicrosoftAccountOptions
        {
            ClientId = "clientId from db", 
            ClientSecret = "secret from db",
            CorrelationCookie =
        {
            HttpOnly = true,
            SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always
        }
        };

        var scheme = new AuthenticationScheme(schemeName, displayName: null, typeof(MicrosoftAccountHandler));
        _schemeProvider.TryAddScheme(scheme);
        _optionsCache.TryAdd(schemeName,schemeOptions);
        var redirectUrl = Url.Action("ExternalLoginCallback", "ExternalAuthentication");
      
        var properties = _signInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties(schemeName, "ExternalAuthentication/ExternalLoginCallback");
        return new ChallengeResult("Microsoft", properties);
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    public async Task<IActionResult> ExternalLoginCallback(string returnUrl = null, string remoteError = null)
    {
        returnUrl = returnUrl ?? Url.Content("~/");

        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(remoteError))
        {
            return LocalRedirect($"Login?externalLoginError={remoteError}");
        }
        var info = await _signInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
        if (info == null)
        {
            return LocalRedirect($"Login?externalLoginError=Error loading external login information");
        }
       
        var signInResult = await _signInManager.ExternalLoginSignInAsync(info.LoginProvider,
            info.ProviderKey, isPersistent: false, bypassTwoFactor: true);

        if (signInResult.Succeeded)
        {                
            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }            
        else
        {
            // Get the email claim value
            var email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email);

            if (email != null)
            {
               
                var user = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync(email);

                if (user == null)
                {
                    user = new ApplicationUser
                    {
                        UserName = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email),
                        Email = info.Principal.FindFirstValue(ClaimTypes.Email)
                    };

                    await _userManager.CreateAsync(user);
                }
                 
                await _userManager.AddLoginAsync(user, info);
                await _signInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent: false);
                 
                return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
            }
            return LocalRedirect($"Login?externalLoginError=Failed to login.");

        }
    }
```

In this case, the ChallengeResult does not route to the Microsoft login page, I was wondering if this is possible to achieve or some other way.